# Not allowing controls to overlap

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, controls

I am have been trying all day to figure out how to not allow controls that I draw on event to check and see if there is another control there and if so to move it over so they do not overlap.  I need them to be able to be overlapping if the user drags them there but on the creation of the control to check and move them if necessary.  I am trying to create a card game and dont want controls to be hidden behind controls (cards) that the user has not yet moved manually.  I am using picture boxes as my cards.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.  Here is a screen shot of my form.  The  darker panels are whats in the players hand.  The panels that are a light grey are the playing field.  Ideally, the user would play a card and it would try and place it in the top left of the panel.  if there is a card that intersects then move it over until it doesn't touch a card.  Basically find a open space to put the card.

[image: Image of Form1]

Comment: What is exactly your question? If you ask me how to check if the space is empty, you can do `myPanel.GetChildAtPoint(checkThisPoint)`. It will return a control that covers that point. You need to develop logic to keep and check positions of all controls

Comment: That is exactly my question.  For example how would I run a loop that would check each (card) picturebox and check it against the newly created picturebox and if they are going to touch each other then move it.  If at that point it touches another then move it again.

Comment: Please check this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/19717325/1704458. This is example, not exactly answer but it could be part of it. You need series of arrays, etc, to keep all the information and compare it in memory. For example, a card stack can be a jugged array. You have array of stacks and in the stack you have array of cards - pure programming :o)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the flow layout panel Class it's under the toolbox=> container with this control you can set how controls are added to it.

Comment: I have tried messing around with it however, wouldn't this affect the user being able to drag the pictureboxes around the form as they wish after they have been added?